# Describing hull of vertex intersections of two convex bounded polytopes?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

We have two convex bounded polytopes $P_1$ and $P_2$ where

a. $P_2\subseteq P_1$

b. $\mathcal{V}(P_2)\cap\mathcal{V}(P_1)\neq\emptyset$.

1. Is there a name for the polytope $P=\mbox{Conv}(\mathcal{V}(P_2)\cap\mathcal{V}(P_1))$?
2. Is there a polynomial time algorithm to describe $P$ by half-spaces

Note $\mathcal{V}(P_2)\cap\mathcal{V}(P_1)=\emptyset\iff P=\emptyset$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak How is this in metric geometry?

Comment: I followed [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/mg.metric-geometry/info) which puts convex geometry under ([tag:mg.metric-geometry]). Of course, I leave it to you as the OP and to more experienced users to choose a more suitable top-level tag if there is one. (For basic info on top-level tags, see: [Why are MO tags formatted as they are?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1457) and [What are top level tags, and why should I try to use them?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075#1076))